# Problem with select from Sqlite Expo. I can't save the array returned by the query through the hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, expo

I'm a beginner with mobile development and I'm using Expo to create an Android application. The problem I'm having is to save the return value of select in my variable. I am using the "hook" in function, instead of a class. 
When running "console.log (users)", an empty array is displayed.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {DatabaseConnection} from '../database/conex';
import {DatabaseInit} from '../database/dbinit';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

var db = null;

export default function viewAllUser(){

    db = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', [], (tx, results) => {
          var temp = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
            temp.push(results.rows.item(i));                               
          }             
          {() => setUsers(temp)}
        });  

      });
     console.log(users);
}
```